# Mongoose aggregate with counting and grouping

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to find records that match a url but return a custom object.

I have this model..

```
const ReactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  url: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  emoji: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['happy', 'sad', 'angry'],
    required: true
  },

  ip: {
    type: String
  }
})
```

I want to query that model and match the `url` but return a response which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "emoji": "happy",
    "count": 4,
    "reacted": true
  },
  {
    "emoji": "sad",
    "count": 9,
    "reacted": false
  },
  {
    "emoji": "angry",
    "count": 7,
    "reacted": false
  }
]
```

I need to be able to calculate on the fly if the `reacted` is true or not by comparing the recorded `ip` with a variable I have in the process.

One attempt was

```
.aggregate([
  {$match: {url}},
  {$group: {
    _id: '$emoji',
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }}
])
```

but I can't seem to concat the ips and see if my variable IP is in that array or not.

Thanks for any help. My first time asking!

Comment: Quick questions: What array are you referring here ? Is that an array of ips for each emoji key in a group ? Is variable ip an user input ?

Comment: variable ip is a user input yeah. I can do `.find({url: url})` and that'll give me an array of `reactions` but I need to return the count and if my ip matches along with just one object showing the emoji type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$push` operator to `$group` stage to create an array of `ip`.

Add a  `$project` stage for renaming `_id` to `emoji` and computing the `reacted` field.

`$setSubset` to compare the previous calculated `ips` array with input variable  and return `true` when the input variable array is a subset of the `ips` array

```
   aggregate([
      {$match: {url}},
      {$group: {
        _id: "$emoji",
        count: {$sum: 1},
        ips:{$push:"$ip"}
      }},
      {$project:{_id:0, emoji:"$_id",count:1, reacted:{ $setIsSubset: [[variableip], "$ips" ] }
      }}
    ])
```

Comment: Booyah! This is exactly what I was trying to do. Mongo blows my mind most days but this is so easy to follow. Thank you ✨